# app crashes because of null values, swift 2

Tags: crash, swift2, ios9, do-catch

I'm trying to get data using JSON ad there is a null value causes crash.

```
let jsonData:NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary

let success:NSInteger = jsonData.valueForKey("success") as! NSInteger
//code error bad instruction

NSLog("Success: %ld", success);
```

how can I turn null to zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let success = (jsonData["success"] as? NSInteger) ?? 0
```

step by step:

1. get the value `jsonData["success"]` (please, don't use `valueForKey`, it does something completely different)
2. `as? NSInteger` - try to cast it to `NSInteger` or return `nil` if it's not a number (in this case, it's a `NSNull` instance)
3. `?? 0` - if `nil`, use a default value of zero

Comment: thank you for your answer but this line has beed activated: `if jsonData["error_message"] as? NSString != nil {
                                error_msg = jsonData["error_message"] as! NSString
                            } else {
                                error_msg = "Unknown Error"
                            }`

Comment: @VahidGR That line does not even appear in the question. If you have more bugs, please, try to fix them first by yourself and then possibly ask another question. Don't forget to also include the JSON data you are trying to parse.